# run an event only when a tab is activated

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to do something when a tab is `activated`

`onvisibilitychange` fires when a page is `activated` and `de-activated`

I need only the first option, something like:

```
document.onactivate = function(){ 
  console.log("index.php is visible");
};
```

Any help?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to detect if a browser window is not currently active?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060008/is-there-a-way-to-detect-if-a-browser-window-is-not-currently-active)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use condition to check visible

```js
document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", function handleVisibilityChange() {
  if (!document.hidden) {
    console.log("index.php is visible");
  }
}, false);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check the `visibilityState` of the document. The event will fire when the page is activated and de-activated, however, this allows you to run code only when the page becomes activated ie: visible.

```
document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", function() {
  if (document.visibilityState === "visible") {
    // code when page is visible
    console.log("index.php is visible");
  }
});
```